# ListView inside SwipeRefreshLayout can't handle onItemLongClick event

Tags: android, listview, swiperefreshlayout

My problem is very simple. I have a ListView inside of SwipeRefreshLayout and I want to handle the onItemLongClick event of the ListView. But it won't recognize it being long clicked, i wonder what is wrong?

This is my XML:

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/swipeContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true"
    android:longClickable="true" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_timeline"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
        android:longClickable="true"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
        android:soundEffectsEnabled="true" >
    </ListView>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

and here's my java file

```
listview.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {

  public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int pos, long id) {
    Log.v(TAG, "Content Clicked!");
    postContentToWall(m1Result.get(pos));
    return true;
  }

});
```

Comment: What means not working? do you get any error?

Comment: no error but no sign of it being longclicked. the Log was never called and postContentToWall function never happened.

Comment: put a `toast` message inside `onItemClick()` and check if it works!

Comment: Your posted code and layout seems fine but I highly suspect the main Activity or Fragment is the issue. And I do not see the code where you define object listview.

Comment: Guys I solved the problem, it was because inside the adapter there's a view.onClickListener. so what i did was, removing my view.onClick and replace it with listview.onClickListener so there's two event handling operations (onItemClick and onItemLongClick). Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys I solved the problem, it was because inside the adapter there's a view.onClickListener. so what i did was, removing my view.onClick and replace it with listview.onClickListener so there's two event handling operations (onItemClick and onItemLongClick). Thanks :)